# How to start a Diagram in Intellij IDEA Enterprise edition MacOS

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I have an enterprise version of IntelliJ IDEA

```
2018.1.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-181.4668.68, built on April 24, 2018

JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b29 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.4
```

I have UML Diagram plugin enabled.

When I select the context menu with a right click there no Diagrams option is available. Command + Shift + U option is also not available.

How can it be resolved?

Comment: Where exactly do you click? [This option is available](https://i.imgur.com/Y68Ngwh.png).

Comment: The same I do in macOS. Is this menu configurable some how? I have far less options

Comment: Please share [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085). Menus are configurable in IDE settings. Options available would depend on context (source root vs just a directory).

Comment: https://ibb.co/eCYnGT

Comment: It's important where you click. In my case the click was performed on the Java source root, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html (blue folder).

Comment: Yep, I have java project with sources as root configured. I click on java simple POJO class. I checked preferences in tools - https://ibb.co/iZe2Y8/ . I also checked log file - nothing is happened when I use the shortcut

Comment: Logs may show what's the problem.

Comment: I have one message in log now. I'm not sure if it is connected. 2018-05-25 10:07:27,557 [73031929]   INFO - .openapi.util.LowMemoryWatcher - Low memory signal received.

Comment: I suggest opening a ticket with support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new and providing the logs/screenshots there.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the support!)